# Laravel 5.1 Wildcard Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm creating a CMS that allows the user to define categories. Categories can either have additional categories under it or pages. How can I create a route in Laravel that will support a potentially unlimited number of URI segments?

I've tried the following....

```
Route::get('/resources/{section}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'MasterController@show']);
```

I also tried making the route optional...

```
Route::get('/resources/{section?}', ['as' => 'show', 'uses' => 'MasterController@show']);
```

Keep in mind, section could be multiple sections or a page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, you need to provide a regular expression to be used to match parameter values. Laravel router treats **/** as parameter separator and you must change that behaviour. You can do it like that:

```
Route::get('/resources/{section}', 
  [
    'as' => 'show', 
    'uses' => 'MasterController@show'
  ])
  ->where(['section' => '.*']);
```

This way, whatever comes after **/resources/** and matches the regular expression will be passed to **$section** variable in your controller.