# Laravel route not working with file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to create a route in Laravel 5.1 that will work for a generic permalink.

```
Route::get('{generic_url}.html', 'Frontend\CMSController@generic');
```

When I go to a URL say /this-is-my-page.html I get a 404 page that does not originate from within Laravel (my custom 404 page does not appear). However, when I go to /index.php/this-is-my-page.html everything works fine.

I believe that this problem is originating from the configuration of the server. My .htaccess is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

As I am still developing this solution, I am using the `php -S localhost:8000` command to launch the web server. Could that be the cause of my problem? Is there something wrong with the default configuration? Should I move my development to a "real" server?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using, I'm assuming 5+ - Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31570581/610880

Comment: @Braunson - that isn't applicable here, as `{generic_url}` would match `this-is-my-page` regardless of the presence of `index.php`.

Comment: @JoshPennington - As I understand it, the old `artisan serve` handled URL rewriting within PHP (I could be wrong). Since this was removed, you need to use an Apache or `.htaccess`-compatible server to enable the default rewriting.

Comment: Can you not use `php artisan serve` instead of `php -S localhost:8000`?

Comment: @MikeRockett Using artisan serve worked. Thank you

Comment: @RossWilson That worked. Thank you